# How to get script's value in .append()?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery

Here is my dropdownlist:

```
<div id="addCam"></div>
                            <div id="addDiv">
                                <select id="type1">
                                    <option value="">- Kiểu áo -</option>
                                    @foreach (var item in Model.teetypes)
                                    {
                                        <option value="@item.Image">@item.Name</option>
                                    }
                                </select>
                                <a class="btn btn-info btn-default" id="addBtnH" style="text-align:center" title="Thêm sản phẩm"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a>
                            </div>
```

And here is my javascript .append():

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var count = 2;
    var maxAppend = 0;
    $("#addBtnH").click(function () {
        var name = $("#type1 option:selected").val();
        var name1 = $("#type1 option:selected").text();
        if (name == '') return;
        if (maxAppend >= 5) {
            $("#addDiv").hide();
            return;
        }
        $("#addDiv").show();
        $("#type1 option:selected").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        $("#type1").val('');

        $("#addCam").append("<div class='widget' id='del" + count + "'><div class='widget-body'><div class='col-md-3'><span style='display:block'><img src='" + name + "' id='tee" + count + "' height='75'/></span></div>" +
            "<div class='col-md-1'><select id='color" + count + "' onchange='changeColor" + count + "()'>@foreach (var item in Model.teecolors){<option value='@item.Color' style='background-color: #@item.Color'></option>}</select></div><div id='dis" + count + "'>" + name1 + "</div>" +
            "<hr class='wide'><input type='text' name='input'><a class='btn btn-info btn-default' rel='"+name+"' id='delete" + count + "' style='text-align:center' title='Xóa sản phẩm'><i class='fa fa-trash'></i></a>" + @*str +*@
            "<script>$('#delete" + count + "').click(function(){var images = $(this).attr('rel'); $('#type1 option[value = "+"images"+"]').removeAttr('disabled');$('#del" + count + "').remove();});" + "<" + "/script>" +
            "<script type='text/javascript'>function changeColor" + count + "(){var eID = document.getElementById('color" + count + "'); var colorVal = eID.options[eID.selectedIndex].value; document.getElementById('tee" + count + "').style.background = '#' + colorVal;}" + "<" + "/script>" +
            "</div></div>");
        count = count + 1;
        maxAppend++;
    });
});
```

My problem is, when I click button add, it will add div as content in append, and the value has been add will be disabled in dropdownlist. In the added div, there is a button delete, when i click it, the div will disappear, and the disabled attribute value will be remove. I create 'images' to get attr('rel') of that button, but i don't know how to let $("#type1 option[value=images]") understand that 'images' is a value, not a string? Please help me!

Answer (score 0):

It is not the best practice to write the scirpts elements into the code to be evaluated.

The technique you are looking for is to continuously use jquery selector to get the appended node and set the attributes dynamically.
Consider this solution:

```js
$("#addCam").append($('<ul>').attr('class', 'some-class')
                     .append($('<li>').attr('class', 'some-other-class')
                             .append($('<img>').attr('src', 'somePath'))
                            .on('click', liClickedHandler)));
```